# install the apache module for passenger (ruby)

Tags: ruby, macos, apache, passenger

I am trying to install the apache module for passenger using the instructions provided at http://modrails.com/install.html

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I installed apache using macports:

```
sudo port install apache2
```

When I run passenger-install-apache2-module it fails, I also tried installing apache from source. Downloaded it from http://httpd.apache.org/ then ran the commands below:

```
./configure --enable-so
make
make install
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8

Please help. My objective is to get started with ruby. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you install apache with macport? Apache is installed on OS X 10.6.x as default.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by failed? Also I've never needed anything but the version of apache that comes with OS X

Comment: You don't need Passenger to get started with Ruby. Passenger is meant to be installed on production servers, usually Linux boxes.

Comment: Turns out that I had to define the apache path variable in .bash_profile. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had to define the apache path variable in .bash_profile